# under the proxy service i can not get client ip

Tags: c#, asmx

there are two asmx service. first service call from client and after first service call second service then i want to get client ip address in second service but it gives  ::1 localhost not getting client ip address.

Can you help me?

i use below method for ip address.

```
   public static string GetUserIP()
        {
            var ip = (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != null
            && HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != "")
            ? HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
            : HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            if (ip.Contains(","))
                ip = ip.Split(',').First().Trim();
            return ip;
        }
```

Comment: The first part of your ternary could be simplified to `var ip = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) ? ... : ...)`

Comment: ok it is true but my problem is HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] is empty or localhost

Comment: Are you running this on your local computer?

Comment: yes i run it on local computer .i can get client ip address in  first service but get localhost address in second service because second service call from first service.

Comment: Can you show how you call the second service? Forwarding a request is not the same as your web service making a request to another one. The HTTP headers aren't created because it isn't getting forwarded, it is just being called from the first service as a normal web request I'm guessing.

Comment: i call with below code part not added extra header 
            `T2.T2WebService service = new T2.T2WebService();
            return service.HelloWorld();`